# looking for a way to stack images in python numpy for dataset geneneration

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to stack numpy array (images). I have around 1000 images each (20,20)  I want stack all images into single array. Currently I am using `np.dstack`. It's giving me an array like (20,20,1000). I want result to like to be (1000,20,20).

Comment: Can you show us what you've done?

Comment: Try the siblings of `np.dstack`, `np.stack`, `np.vstack`, `np.hstack`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141267/stacking-arrays-in-new-dimension-numpy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stacking arrays in new dimension (numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141267/stacking-arrays-in-new-dimension-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html?highlight=stack#numpy.stack), the axis along which the arrays are stacked can be specified.

Example from the documentation:

```
>>> arrays = [np.random.randn(3, 4) for _ in range(10)]
>>> np.stack(arrays, axis=0).shape
(10, 3, 4)
```